# WSO2 EI How to create a xml file having attributes in it

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working on one scenario where I have to create a sequence in APIM 2.6.0. To create a sequence file I am using WSO2 EI 6.4.0

Can it be created using payload mediator. Currently, I am using data mapper mediator and somehow I have achieved also but was thinking if there is any other way as well.

Here is the sequence file which I am trying to create in EI

```
            <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Dynamic-Sequence_throughAPI-EICAPI">
    <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="inputmessage"
                expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/messagefile')"
                scope="default"
                type="STRING"/>


    <property name="messageType"
                value="application/json"
                scope="axis2"
                type="STRING"/>
    <property name="ContentType"
                value="application/json"
                scope="axis2"
                type="STRING"/>



    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint name="ctctokenURL">
            <http method="POST"
                uri-template="https://example.com/auth"/>
        </endpoint>



    </call>



    <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
                expression="get-property('resource')"
                scope="axis2"
                type="STRING"/>
    <property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
    </sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since sequence is in xml, you can use PayloadFactory mediator or Datamapper to achieve your need. If you want more control and flexibility, you can choose to use a Class mediator or a Script mediator and write the logic yourself.

Comment: thank you. I have used XSLT mediator to construct the message.